# Problem with quadratics and exponentiation

Tags: exponential-function

I was bored and started solving the following equation:

$$2^x = x^2$$

I can see two solutions:
$x = 2$ and $x = 4$.
WolframAlpha tells me there is one more, but I can hardly get the two I mentioned above (at which I arrived with empirical methods).
I fear this might be outside the realm of my Maths skills (up to multivariable calculus).

Comment: To edit your equation, simply put it into dollar signs, i.e. `$2^x = x^2$`. You can use any latex commands you find useful then.

Comment: [Here you can find a tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to use $\LaTeX$ commands on this site.

Comment: See [Lambert *W* function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Comment: The same question is treated here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591124/solve-2x-x2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are asking (I assume you are) about how to get these two results analytically, I am almost certain that there is no way to get a closed solution to the equation $a^x = x^a$, except for special cases like $a=2$ in your case. In that case, using plots to have a look at how many solutions you can expect is useful:

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+2%5Ex-x%5E2

You can see that there is another solution for some negative value of $x$, which you probably cannot get without numeric methods.

For the positive solutions, some things can actually be said without resorting to numeric methods.

You can show that for $x<2$, the function $2^x - x^2$ is positive, since it is increasing at $x=0$, decreasing at $x=2$ and is concave on $[0,2]$.

For $x>2$, you can show that because the function is convex, it can have at most two zeroes on $$[2,\infty).

Together, these two points show that the only positive solutions to your equation are $2$ and $4$

Comment: That's very interesting, I will most definitely look further  into it

Answer (score 0):

In Wolfram, use

solve x^2 - 2^x = 0

To find the negative solution to be about -0.766665

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%5E2+-+2%5Ex+%3D+0