# Solution to equation $2^x $ = $x^8$

Tags: exponentiation

I was able to solve this equation using graphical methods, but cannot figure out a mathematical solution to the equation.
 What approach should be taken to solve it?

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/591124/solve-2x-x2).

Comment: It's a transcendental equation. You can not solve it in elementary functions.

Comment: Depends on what kind of solutions you are looking for. If you want integer solutions, then arithmetic is you friend :-)

Comment: @NicolasFRANCOIS: a grapher quickly shows that there are no integer solutions, and you can formalize by exhibiting integers between which the curves cross..

Comment: @DietrichBurde: IMO a very different question. The one is asking "why?", the other "how?".

Comment: @YvesDaoust You are right. It should be a duplicate of the first one. This type of question is also popular, I think.

Comment: @YvesDaoust : yeah, but with arithmetic arguments, you don't need a grapher : $x$ must be a power of $2$, $x=2^k$, which leads to $2^{2^k}=2^{8k}$, $2^{k-3}=k$, and you stay with only a few cases to study, all of which failing (or you can continue saying $k$ must be a power of $2$...)

Comment: @Yves Daoust, you are right, it's not really a match, but there is an answer there explaining "how".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation has explicit solutions in terms of [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). In the real domain, there are three roots
$$x_{1,2}=-\frac{8 }{\log (2)}W_0\left(\pm\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)$$
$$x_3=-\frac{8 }{\log (2)}W_{-1}\left(-\frac{\log (2)}{8}\right)$$
Have a look to the Wikipedia page for the manipulations and the series expansions for the numerical evaluation of them.

In the complex domain, I guess that there as much more.