# Analytical way to find the third root of $x^{2}=2^{x}$ other than 2 and 4

Tags: real-analysis

How to find analytically the third root (-ve) of $x^{2}=2^{x}$ other than 2 and 4?

Does differentiation of the equation make a sensible way?

I tried with $\log_a$ for different $a$' s. But I couldn't find the root.

Comment: See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PI1NeGtJo7s

Comment: What does “(-ve)” mean?

Comment: @gen-zreadytoperish "-ve" is a semi-common shorthand for "negative". You also have "+ve".

Comment: Learn to search with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E2%3D2%5Ex%24&p=1) before posting.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/965836/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/591124/42969.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking for the negative solution, we get
$$
x^2=2^x\\
x^2=e^{x\ln 2}\\
-x=e^{x/2\cdot\ln 2}\\
-xe^{-x/2\cdot\ln 2}=1\\
-\frac x2\ln 2e^{-x/2\cdot\ln 2}=\frac12\ln 2\\
-\frac x2\ln 2=W\left(\frac{\ln 2}2\right)\\
x=-\frac{2W\left(\frac{\ln 2}2\right)}{\ln 2}\approx-0.766665
$$
where the sign on the left-hand side in line 3 comes from knowing that $x$ is negative, and $W$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Which is to say, $W(1/2\cdot\ln 2)$ is the solution to
$$
ye^y=\frac{\ln 2}2
$$

Comment: In my opinion you have been here long enough to suspect that this is a duplicate. Did you search? [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24x%5E2%3D2%5Ex%24&p=1) gave many hits, granted some in AOPS.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Approach0 still does not work at all on mobile. Neither does the "related questions" column. So I am basically blind in that regard, compared to you. It is, in other words, a _lot_ easier for me to just answer than it is to look for duplicates. Also, you are a lot more concerned about duplicates than I am. I am a lot more concerned about answers in comments than you are. We all have our differences.

Comment: While we need to respect differences of opinion, the point raised by @JyrkiLahtonen is important. I also use this site exclusively on mobile and have issues searching, but would prefer to close duplicates than answer them.

Comment: There is also [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B+x%5E2+%3D+2%5Ex+%7D%24) and that *does* work on mobile devices.

Comment: @MartinR: I have used it on some occasions (you had mentioned it sometime ago to me). While it's not as good as approach0, it is helpful.

Comment: I answer in a comment for many a reason. One of the more frequent ones is that I suspect the question to be a duplicate.